# React bootstrap property gives error Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `fluid`

Tags: reactjs, properties, styles, react-bootstrap

Copmponents in my app, for example

```
   <Container fluid >
      <Row className="black-bar"> 
        <p>
          Free Shipping Worldwide
        </p>
      </Row>
    </Container>
```

gives the following error : Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `fluid`.
If I correct it as suggested, like fluid="true", the prop stops working and solutions such as fluid={true} produces the same error.

Comment: what is your react-bootstrap version? are you using typescript?

Comment: Its, v2.1.2, and I dont use typescript, but the problem is solved. See 1st answer.

Comment: I still wondering why you was getting this message.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a + sign before defining the prop as true:fluid={+true}.